# Al usar include, no toma la ruta definida donde están los archivos

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

tengo este codigo donde el include no asume el path del archivo php requerido.

```
<form method="POST">
    
    include'/cliente/Vista/formRegistrarCliente.php';
    
Este es el mensaje de Error : 
Warning: include(formRegistrarCliente.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\cliente\Modelo\ModificarRegistros.php on line 33
```

Comment: Sin ver el código, es imposible ayudarte. Además, ¿existe el archivo? Muestra un [repro]. Lee [ask].

Comment: Saludos. Verifica la ruta; esto desde donde lo invocas; puede ser que la ruta desde raíz no sea la correcta; prueba especificando la ruta relativa.

Comment: sera que tu problema es con php, y no con phpmyadmin, que es un gestor para el motor mysql?